# Unable to load environment variable (.env) in Django App

Tags: django

I am trying to launch a Django project and am unable to do so because it seems my local environment is disconnected from my .env file in the root directory. I've never had this problem before and assume there is an easy fix but I can't seem to figure it out. When I run basic commands like runserver I get the following error:

```
RATE_LIMIT_DURATION = int(os.environ.get("RATE_LIMIT_DURATION"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

In my .env file, I have defined the variable as:

```
RATE_LIMIT_DURATION = 10
```

I have already confirmed that my database is setup and I am pretty sure my settings are in good shape otherwise.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": 8000,
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the traceback of error, so it would give more understanding of the problem

Comment: can you try removing space around RATE_LIMIT_DURATION in .env? Basically RATE_LIMIT_DURATION=10

Comment: Where do you read the `.env` file exactly? Do note that `os.environ` reads the environment variables set in your (well for a lack of a better word) environment, it does not know anything about that file.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to include .env to my django project I just use `load_dotenv` from dotenv python library.

So basically in `settings.py` I put:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

Comment: [Link to dotenv library](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)